# Processing SSAS Cube with new columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I have a couple of dimensions in the data warehouse that are built dynamically using dynamic sql on every load day (every day). On every load the dimensions are dropped and recreated using dynamic sql and new columns added/old columns are dropped.

If I process the cube, I get errors related to invalid columns because those columns are not existing in the underlying dimension table but are still in the cube dimension attributes.

Is there a way through SSIS to process the cube to always point to the latest list of columns while processing?

I have tried processing the cube within SSDT using "Full", "Process Update" etc. but still no luck.

I don't want to manually update the dimension attributes in the cube.

Thanks in advance. Any input is appreciated.

Regards, 
SAhmed

Comment: You can create a script task that generates a dynamic XMLA command and executes it.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Thanks for the input. Based on this I was researching on examples of processing the dimensions using dynamic XMLA but I had no luck. I am not sure if I am looking for the correct information. Do you have an example that could give me a little more direction? - 
Thanks

Comment: I don't have any examples handy, but maybe if you tell us what you found and what part of it is giving you trouble we might be able to clarify and focus your effort.   Another thing you might look at is BiML, which I have no experience with personally, but have heard good things about from other users here.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I would do some additional research. I am not in a rush to implement this. I will update later. Thanks.